# $(window).height() is not working in IE10

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-10

I want set height of DIV as per the window size, but `$(window).height()` returns `0` in IE10, It works fine in IE8 and IE9. Why?

Also I have written doctype statement as follows

```
<!--[if IE]>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">`
<![endif]-->
```

if i remove "`<!--[if IE]>`" and "`<![endif]-->`" then it works fine. Why? Please explain.

Comment: What is your DOCTYPE?

Comment: jQuery's $(window).height() is sensitive to doctype. What is yours?

Comment: +1 to the comments above. Also what version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: doctype is <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

Comment: jquery version is jQuery v1.8.3

Comment: In Internet Explorer 10 HTML conditional comments are not supported. What is used as doctype when browser is not IE?

Comment: No doctype when browser is not IE.

Comment: Then thats your problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Irvin Dominin said, jQuery's $(window).height() is sensitive to doctype. Since Internet Explorer 10 conditional comments are not supported, and you don't have a doctype when the browser isn't IE - jQuery's $(window).height() breaks.

Comment: I am thinking of giving Doctype for all browsers not only for IE. Hence removing conditional comments. :-)

Comment: Good idea, you should always have a doctype.

Answer (score 1):

it working if you remove `"<!--[if IE]>" and "<![endif]-->"`, coz as you mentioned if/else for IE then Other browsers aren't able to detect DOCTYPE which is gracefully needed because `$(window).height()` will not work. if doctype is not defined. So please add DOCTYPE for all browsers, problem could be resolve